# Expect script <<sudo - instructions >> doesn't work

Tags: expect

I need to set by Expect  a date (ex. 02/28/2024) on a
Blade server (here below showed as litp-admin@ipaddress_2)

In pratice something as here below

---

ssh - t root@ip_address1  ssh litp-admin@ipaddress_2
su -  (switch root)
date -s "mm/dd/year"
I tried in expect  but without success

---

Any idea?

A possible solution , un example working.
I need this for my work

Comment: please reformat your post. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting